# Getting IMEI with adb command from device on Android 14

Tags: android, bash, adb, imei, android-14

I'm using command:
`adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"`
It was working fine on Android 13, but now it gives partly broken IMEI, where 3 numbers came as **'** symbol
[image: results screenshot]
It's not just these are additional symbols, what i mean is that exactly 3 numbers comes as symbol
As far as i know, every Android 14 devices with IMEI is affected.

I've tried to use command
`adb  shell service call phone 146 i32 0 s16 com.android.shell | cut -d "'" -f2| grep -Eo '[0-9]'| xargs| sed 's/\ //g'`
as per dougstar [potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77183428/11723546), but it's also for Android 13, plus it does give me an error.
[image: an error]

//update

Even though original command which i'm using now showing wrong results, it is caused because it catches wrong columns [(thanks to micha pringle explaination)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260715/11723546)
It could be fixed with changing from 52-66 columns to 50-64 columns for Android 14 devices

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell | cut -c 50-64 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

Comment: Don't put images in your question, write your code directly

Comment: also, this is normal that you get this message : you are trying to execute a bash command in powershell

Comment: In your first example, it works because of quotes : you are passing all your arguments to `adb shell " ... "`. You could try the same in your second example by using correct quotation

Comment: Something like `adb  shell "service call phone 146 i32 0 s16 com.android.shell | cut -d \"'\" -f2| grep -Eo '[0-9]'| xargs| sed 's/\ //g'"` might work, though I can't test it myself

Comment: @Aserre thanks for explaining why one thing was working and other wasn't. I've succesefully used your command and it gives me the response `40`
If we try to remove all additional code which formats text for only specific part to be shown, the full answer is: `'..../...P.a.r.c.''e.l. .d.a.t.a. .''n.o.t. .f.u.l.l.''y. .c.o.n.s.u.m.''e.d.,. .u.n.r.e.''a.d. .s.i.z.e.:.' ' .4.0.......    ')`

Answer (score 0):

Even though original command which i'm using now showing wrong results, it is caused because it catches wrong columns [(thanks to micha pringle explaination)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260715/11723546)
It could be fixed with changing from 52-66 columns to 50-64 columns for Android 14 devices

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell | cut -c 50-64 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

Answer (score 0):

**First some comments:**

- Using `adb shell "some_command | cut"` is using cut on the phone but the phone doesn't necessarily have it so I suggest using `adb shell "some_command" | cut` to use cut on the pc;
- On Windows you could simply get BusyBox to have all commands available without installation (just download from https://frippery.org/busybox/ and then run `busybox.exe ash`);
- `cut` by column is highly unreliable as you can see, `cut` by separator is better;
- Most people miss the most important parameter of cut `-s`, this will skip the lines that doesn't contain decoded data (decoded data is between `'` and `'`) since `iphonesubinfo` response may contains them.

**Response:**

So, this is the most reliable command (executed from `busybox ash` or `bash`):

`adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell" | cut -d "'" -f 2 -s | tr -d '.[:space:]'`

**Script:**

This is my script that does that and even more: https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer/blob/main/utils/device-info.sh